# How to add UIGestureRecognizer to WKInterfaceImage?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Currently I am working with apple watch kit app.
I want to add `UIGestureRecognizer` to `WKInterfaceImage`. 
Is it possible to add `UIGestureRecognizer` to any WatchKit app control?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only possible answers are "Yes" or "No", and will merely reference the developer documentation the OP should be reading anyways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gesture recognition in Apple Watch (WatchKit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524733/gesture-recognition-in-apple-watch-watchkit)

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic, because the question implies "how do I get this done", but it is a duplicate of the question Lukas Kukacka noted.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that.

*WatchKit* does not support anything from ***UI***Kit, therefore it also does not support ***UI***GestureRecognizer.

Comment: Is there any controls in watch kit which can provide me same features or functionality like gesture?

Comment: is there anyway to interact with the Watch except via touch, swipe, force touch or crown wheel?

Comment: So if I want to make a WKInterfaceImage clickable, I am screwed.... great idea, Apple.

Comment: @Josh That is what `WKInterfaceButton` is for. It supports background images.