# WKInterfaceTable: Swipe to edit like the stock Mail app

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, watchos, wkinterfacetable

In the stock Apple Watch mail app you can swipe left to access more options for an email. How would I go about doing this with a `WKInterfaceTable`?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple guideline that it is not possible in watchOS to implement custom gesture as we have in `iOS`. Because gestures in `watchOS`  manage by OS itself.

What Apple says:

> User interactions on Apple Watch generate touch events and gestures, but unlike iOS apps, your Watch apps don’t handle these events directly. The system provides automatic responses for all touch events and gestures, responding in the following ways:

```
•   Taps trigger action-based events in your app
•   Vertical swipes scroll the current screen
•   Horizontal swipes display the previous or next page in a page-based interface
•   Left edge swipes navigate back to a parent screen in a hierarchical interface
```

When the user taps a button or another control, Apple Watch calls that control’s associated action method. You define action methods for the controls in your interface and use them to respond to user interactions.

[More on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524733/gesture-recognition-in-apple-watch-watchkit)

[Apple guideline](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/)