# How to add row actions to WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I cannot find any documentation or tutorial for this.

On iOS it is easy to add a "swipe right-to-left" action to a UITableViewCell. Such as in the mail app you can swipe on an email to get more options.

This same feature is implemented in the watchOS Messages app as seen here:

[image: Swiping right to left on message]

As you can see, I've swipe across on a cell and the "Bin" option is now shown.

How would I implement this?

Sorry for the vague question, but I just cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open UITableView edit action buttons programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically)

Comment: it isn't this is for WatchOS not iOS

Comment: Sadly there are quite a few UI actions that have dedicated APIs on iOS and are also used by system apps on watchOS, but are not available to developers. This is one of them. Another example is the pull to refresh in the Mail app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gesture recognition in Apple Watch (WatchKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524733/gesture-recognition-in-apple-watch-watchkit)